# Detener proceso de cmd iniciado en C# al cerrar la aplicación

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ffmpeg

Estoy haciendo una aplicación la cual usa ffmpeg. Al iniciar la aplicación y utilizar ffmpeg se abre el cmd, y no hay problema, todo perfecto, pero estoy buscando la forma de cerrar ese cmd junto con la aplicación y no lo he conseguido, al cerrar la app el cmd obviamente permanece abierto.

Para poner en marcha el cmd con sus respectivas líneas, utilizo Process.Start.

Dejo el código que estoy utilizando:

```
public void btnStartRecording_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Tiempo = DateTime.Now;
            Timer1.Enabled = true;
            VideoName = "Video." + Strings.Format(DateTime.Now, "dd-MM-yyyy.HH.mm.ss") + ".avi";
            if (RadioTwoTrack.Checked == true)
            {
                RecMic();
                RecSpeaker();
            }
            else
            {
                RecSpeaker();
            }

            Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k ffmpeg -hide_banner -f gdigrab -show_region 1 -r 30 -i desktop -b:v 9000k Recordings/" + VideoName + "");
            
        }

        private void BtnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
            StopRec();
        }

        public void StopRec()
        {
            if (RadioTwoTrack.Checked == true)
            {
                if (AudioMic.waveIn is object)
                {
                    AudioMic.waveIn.StopRecording();
                }

                if (AudioDesktop.waveIn is object)
                {
                    AudioDesktop.waveIn.StopRecording();
                }
            }
            else if (AudioDesktop.waveIn is object)
            {
                AudioDesktop.waveIn.StopRecording();
            }

            GrabadorPantalla.My.MyProject.Computer.Audio.Stop();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para asegurarte que cierras el proceso correcto, puedes guardar el Id como una propiedad. Este está disponible desde el momento en que lo creas.

```
// tu clase...
private int ProcessId {get; private set;}

public void btnStartRecording_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Tiempo = DateTime.Now;
        Timer1.Enabled = true;
      // ... El resto de tu clase
```

En el momento de creación del proceso:

```
var process = Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k ffmpeg -hide_banner -f gdigrab -show_region 1 -r 30 -i desktop -b:v 9000k Recordings/" + VideoName + "");

this.ProcessId = process.Id;
```

Luego, cuando en el evento Close:

```
Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(ProcessId);
proc.Kill();
```

De esta manera cierras el proceso que fue iniciado por tu aplicación.

Comment: Tienes mi voto,

Answer (score 1):

En el **evento Close** del formulario pon este código:

```
foreach (Process proceso in Process.GetProcesses())
{
   if (proceso.ProcessName == "cmd")
   {
      proceso.Kill();
   }
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es recorrer todos los procesos abiertos y si se encuentra un proceso cuyo nombre es **"cmd"** se cierra ese proceso.

**Nota:** para trabajar con procesos debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Comment: Qué ocurre si tiene más de un proceso en la consola? Qué tal si tiene otras instancias de la consola legítimamente abiertos para otros servicios? Un servicio WCF self hosted, por ejemplo? Se van a cerrar todos? Si ese es el caso, no sería mejor obtener el PID?

Comment: Exactamente se cierran todas las consolas tal como dices,  el pid es una buena opcion... pero dejemos que el op decida, no nos adelantemos, si puede ser simple dejalo simple